# Doing bulk insert or delete before bulk insert in one query PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have these tables:

- tests (id, name)
- test_students (id, test_id, user_id)
- test_teachers (id, test_id, teacher_id)

I need to update the record if `test` exists, `testId` will be passed from frontend.

I am doing `Model.upsert()`, it will update the record if it finds `id` or `id` is passed otherwise it will insert.

Now I need to delete all records from `test_students` and `test_teachers`  and insert again with new data if record is updated otherwise insert in bulk.

```
async upsertTest(data) {
  return sequelize.transaction(transaction => {
   const [test, isCreated] = await Test.upsert(data, { transaction)
   if (isCreated) {
     test.students = await Student.bulkCreate(data.students, { transaction });
     test.teachers = await Teacher.bulkCreate(data.teachers, { transaction });
     return test;
   }
   await Student.destroy({ where: { id test.id }})
   await Teacher.destroy({ where: { id test.id }})
   test.students = await Student.bulkCreate(data.students, { transaction });
     test.teachers = await Teacher.bulkCreate(data.teachers, { transaction });
     return test;
  });
}
```

This code works. But I am thinking to combine both if condition in one query with something like below but I am not sure.

```
with data (test_id, user_id) as (
  values ('t1', 'u1'), ('t1', 'u2'), ('t3', 'u3')
), changed as (
  insert into test_students (test_id, user_id) 
  select * from test_students
  on conflict (test_id) do nothing
)
delete from t where (test_id, user_id) not in (select test_session_id, user_id from data);
```

Comment: `insert into test_students (test_id, user_id)   select * from test_students` looks wrong unless your goal is to duplicate the entire table each time.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name NO, don't want to duplicate the entire table. I am just trying to delete all records from `test_students` or `test_faculties` where `test_id` already existing and insert the new records in tables respectively.

Comment: Then why do you (try to) insert all rows from `test_students` into `test_students`?

Comment: That's a mistake.